# Use of errorCallback destroys component upon caught failure

Tags: lightning-web-components

So this is a bit of a wtf. I've inherited a codebase where I added an errorCallback. Turns out codebase was a bit of a mess and had some loose ends.

Since adding callback, while I am now able to log exceptions (which in this case don't exactly detail what happened), they also started to actually cause failures to bubble up where code before, even when erroneous - worked ok.

Example:

**Parent**

```
<template>
    im dad
    <c-some-child></c-some-child>
</template>


import {LightningElement} from 'lwc'

export default class Some extends LightningElement {
    errorCallback(error, stack) {
        console.error(error, stack)
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
<template>
    im a child
    <lightning-button onclick={missingHandler} label="lost"></lightning-button>
</template>

import {LightningElement} from 'lwc'

export default class SomeChild extends LightningElement {
    // missingHandler(){} // simulates missing handler
}
```

Clicking on button will make the child component disappear. If you remove errorCallback - component remains functional (it will show a modal in LEX, but will suppress in communities).

Question - is there a way to errorCallback to handle exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that when you implement `errorCallback`, the LWC framework has the behavior you described: the offending child component is destroyed. This behavior can't be avoided by any means.

When I was checking this behavior out in the Experience Cloud (Communities) context, I found that the child component is destroyed whether or not you implement `errorCallback`. So if your goal is for the child component not to be destroyed, but to gracefully handle the error and allow the user to proceed as if nothing happened, I believe the best you can hope for is to do this in Lightning Experience.

Fortunately, there is another way besides `errorCallback` to take action on errors in Lightning Experience: **listening for the [Window error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event)**:

```js
connectedCallback() {
  window.addEventListener("error", ({ error }) => {
    console.error("Error happened!", error.message, error.stack);
  });
}
```

This approach doesn't allow you to catch and handle the errors that bubble up to the window level, but it should be sufficient for logging purposes.

[See demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-rtccli?file=src/modules/x/app/app.js)

Comment: `I found that the child component is destroyed whether or not you implement errorCallback `
That might depend on whether or not you've enabled debug mode. Which I can't test right now because of other bugs I found, lol!

Comment: Tested in a LWR Site with and without Lightning Component Debug Mode enabled. The child component is destroyed even though `errorCallback` is not implemented.

Answer (score -1):

The errorCallback method in Lightning web components is designed to handle unhandled exceptions in the component. When an exception occurs in a component, the framework calls the errorCallback method, which receives the error and the stack trace as arguments. By default, if an unhandled exception occurs, the component is destroyed and an error message is displayed.

In your example, the errorCallback method is logging the error to the console, but it is not preventing the component from being destroyed. To handle the exception and prevent the component from being destroyed, you need to return false from the errorCallback method. This tells the framework that the exception has been handled and the component should not be destroyed.

Here's an updated example that returns false from the errorCallback method:

Parent

```
<template>
    im dad
    <c-some-child></c-some-child>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Some extends LightningElement {
    errorCallback(error, stack) {
        console.error(error, stack);
        return false; // Handle the error and prevent the component from being destroyed
    }
}
```

Child

```
<template>
    im a child
    <lightning-button onclick={missingHandler} label="lost"></lightning-button>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class SomeChild extends LightningElement {
    // missingHandler(){} // simulates missing handler
}
```

Returning false from the errorCallback method will prevent the component from being destroyed and allow the user to continue using the component even if an error occurs. However, it's important to handle the error properly and provide appropriate feedback to the user so they understand what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: This answer sounds good on the surface, but it's unsupported by the documentation  (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_error). Nor does it seem to actually be true. See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-opdws9?file=src/modules/x/app/app.js

Comment: Returning true/false doesn't solve the problem :|